# OpenCV 2.3.1 CreateSeq alternative

Tags: opencv

The function **CreateSeq** is not more available in the latest version of OpenCV (2.3.1)
So, what could be an alternative? I need to substitute CreateSeq in the example script **squares.py**

Comment: Are you sure it's removed? it's mentioned in [online 2.3 documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html#createseq), I doubt they have removed an API function in a minor release...

Comment: it's mentioned and available for the C/C++ version, but there is no trace of it in the python wrapper

Comment: Probably a bug then, you should report it